# Word- VBA- How To Automatically Run Code Before Printing?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Document has shading `wdColorGray25` by default.  I want to be able to remove all shading before printing (or saving as a PDF) but this doesn't seem to work as simple as it would in Excel (the code works fine by itself in a standard module).

```
Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

In other words, if I hit **Ctrl+P**, the document will remove the shading before printing and then apply it back after printing.  Would also like the change to be reflected in the print preview as well.

If I select the **FilePrint** command and hit **Create** it generates the following code (not `Application.PrintOut`):
[image]

```
Sub FilePrint()
'
' FilePrint Macro
' Prints the active document
'
    Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show

End Sub
```

If I modify the code to:

```
Sub PrintOut()
' PrintOut runs when you use Ctrl + P

    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With

    Application.PrintOut
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray25
        End With
    End With
    

End Sub
```

And then hit **Ctrl+P**, you can see from the below screenshot below that the text shading still appears.
[image]

However, if I change the name of the sub like below, it will print without the shading but the print preview pane does not appear (it just prints directly without any prompts in between).

```
Sub PrintPreviewandPrint()
' PrintOut runs when you use Ctrl + P

    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With

    Application.PrintOut
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray25
        End With
    End With
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word, you can capture the built-in commands to modify them. To see how this works, try these steps:

1. In Word, choose **Developer>Macros**.
2. Change the *Macros in* dropdown to **Word commands**.
3. Find and select **FilePrint**.
4. Change the *Macros in* dropdown back to **Normal.dotm**.
5. Click on the **Create** button. Word creates a new macro titled with the command name.

```
Sub PrintOut()
' PrintOut runs when you use Ctrl + P

    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With

    Application.PrintOut
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray25
        End With
    End With
    

End Sub
```

```
Sub FilePrint()
'
' FilePrint Macro
' Prints the active document
'

    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        End With
    End With

    Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show

    With ActiveDocument.Styles("example").Font
        With .Shading
            .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray25
        End With
    End With


End Sub
```

Now add your code to modify the style before and after the *Dialogs* line, removing the shading before and adding it after.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I did exactly what you said and it worked however, I edited my question because I should have specified I want it to be done automatically versus having to manually run the code (hence why I was looking at **TheDocument** section to add the code)

Comment: You don't have to run the code manually. There are several different print commands that are invoked by different operations in the user interface. You will have to modify them all to capture every print method. Ctrl + P invokes _Application.PrintOut_ instead of FilePrint.

Comment: Thank you.  I edited your answer to reflect your feedback.  However, these effects still only work if I run the macros manually but if I were to press **Ctr+P** or **Print Preview**, they would still not perform unless I hit F5.

Comment: That's because you called the sub _FilePrintDefault_. As I mentioned previously, Ctrl + P does not run FilePrintDefault: it runs Application.PrintOut. Call the sub _PrintOut_ and Ctrl + P will run it.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I edited my question in response to your feedback.  However, **Ctrl+P** still does not remove the shading.

Comment: I test all code before posting and it's working here. I think you have to do a little debugging. Try recording a macro where you use Ctrl + P and see what VBA gets recorded, then modify that.

Comment: When I record the macro using Ctrl+P, it records _Application.PrintOut_. How do I debug when I am not getting any errors?  What version of Word are you using?  I find it odd that when you select FilePrint, that it generates _Application.PrintOut_ whereas for me it doesn't.  I tried opening up another document and trying there and it still didn't work.

Comment: An alternative sub name that may work better for you is _PrintPreviewandPrint_. If all else fails, you can assign the Ctrl + P shortcut to the macro and remove it from the PrintPreviewandPrint command.

Comment: Almost there sir.  I updated my question to reflect the your recommendation to change to _PrintPreviewandPrint_ but there is no print preview.

Comment: I've answered your original question long ago, and you keep piling on more. I'm not here to write your macro for you. I would appreciate an upvote, thanks.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  Yes of course.  Thank you sir.